# (SEO) - What Is The Side Effects Of Copying Main Site Content To Mobile Site?

Tags: seo

What do you think about copying our content (text content especially) from our main site (eg: mysite.com) to mobile site (eg: m.mysite.com OR mysite.com/m). What is the SEO side effects of doing this? Does SEO experts recommends this or not?

If you have external articles or reference, hope you guys can share here also. :)

Thank you.

Comment: This is more suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com. It's not a programming related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is Google's official stance on mobile SEO](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ch/2012/06/recommendations-for-building-smartphone.html)

Answer (score 0):

Google has a separate spider for mobile content. If you copy mainsite to m.yoursite.com, it works best and your domain authority will just get transfered. No dupe content penalty.